# How can I give names to virtual desktops in xmonad?

Tags: linux, xmonad

I would like the name of a virtual desktop to be displayed when I switch to that desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with the [XMonad.Layout.ShowWName](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Layout-ShowWName.html) layout modifier.